# Date arithmetic in C++

Tags: c++, cygwin

I have been trying to write a C++ program, that requires me to do date arithmetic.
For example today's date (9-30-2014) minus 4 days and have it return 9-26-2014, or today date plus 3 days returning 10-3-2014.
My original thought process is to use

ctime

which will return the date in seconds from jan 1 1970, I could then add or subtract a set number of seconds for the number of days and pass the result into "put_time" a part of

iomanip

to start I am just trying to get this method to print the correct date, but I can not get the compiler to recognize "put_time"

I am using eclipse version (4.4.0)
with  "version 4.1.11(2)-release (x86_64-unknown-cygwin)" as a compiler

From research I have found that "put_time" is only included in certain versions of c++ and I tried running this command

```
`-std=c++0x`
```

However I am still receiving the same error "'put_time' was not declared in this scope".

this is the code I am running so far:

```
//============================================================================
// Name        : Date.cpp
// Author      : me
// Version     :
// Copyright   : Your copyright notice
// Description : date calculations
//============================================================================

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>      // std::put_time
#include <ctime>        // std::time_t, struct std::tm, std::localtime
#include <chrono>       // std::chrono::system_clock
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!

    time_t timer;

     time(&timer);

     cout << timer;

     struct tm * ptm = localtime(&timer);

     cout << put_time(ptm,"%c");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "version 4.1.11(2)-release (x86_64-unknown-cygwin)" isn't a compiler, it's a compiler *version*. Which compiler is it the version of? The current cygwin gcc is 4.9.0, and there never was a 4.1.11 release (the last 4.1.x gcc was in *2007*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use `asctime`?  It's prototype is `char* asctime (const struct tm * timeptr);` and you should not have any problem printing out he char*.  The only issue is that the output format is fixed as `Www Mmm dd hh:mm:ss yyyy` where Www represents the three-letter abbreviation of the day of the week.

If you want more flexibility in the format of the output string, you can use `strftime` to get custom formatting.  It's prototype is `size_t strftime (char* ptr, size_t maxsize, const char* format,const struct tm* timeptr );`